# For looping a certain amount of times

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a helper function that takes 'data' from a previous function and adds it into a dictionary. But I'm having trouble selecting only 10 at a time:

```
def creating_only_10(data, only10):
    for row in data:
        yearr = row[-1]
        if yearr not in only10:
            only10[yearr] = []
        only10[yearr].append([row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3]])
    return(only10)
```

Right now the function takes all of the data and puts it into the dictionary, for instance:

```
{'2000':[[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12], ...]}
```

However, I'm having trouble finding a way where it stops at `[10]` and then continues at `[20]`, any advice or tips would be appreciated!

Output I'm trying to achieve:

```
{'2000': [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10]],
 '2001': [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10]]}
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve here. Could you clarify what output you want?

Comment: @Sam just updated the question!

Comment: What is your input data?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that years contain a list of years:

```
only10 = {}
for year in years:
    tempList = []
    for row in range(10):
    # range(10) = 0 to 9
        tempList.append([row+1]) 

    only10[year] = tempList
```

Note that you need the list (tempList) as a container, so the output will look like:
{'2000': [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10]], '2001': [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10]], '2002': [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10]]}
not like:
{'2000': [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],
 '2001': [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10]} (which is simply not possible)
I still have a strong feeling this is not the best approach but I would need to get more context to confirm this and advise.